# How Can I Dry Up Resource Routes That Use 'Module'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, namespaces, routes

I currently have my application divided into 2 separate namespaces, `admin` and `public`.

Although all my public controllers are within a `public` module, I don't want the routes to include the namespace, so my resources look like this:

```
# config/routes.rb

resources :galleries, only: [:index, :show], module: :public do
  resources :photos, only: [:show], module: :public
end
resources :pages, only: :show, module: :public
resources :tags, only: [:show, :index], module: :public
```

**The use of `module: :public` on each resource is annoying me. How can I dry this up?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what the `scope` method is for (it doesn't just work for module, you can also use it for controller,namespace etc...). The example given in the routing guide is

```
scope module: 'admin' do
  resources :posts, :comments
end
```